# Prevent xmlns=" " added to copy element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file where i want to copy some element using XSLT, But it's adding xmlns=" " in copied element.

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:x="http://www.example.com/rsd/DataAccess" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="x"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="x:Adapter[@Key='AuditLogging']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <Adapter Key="AutoExport"></Adapter>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
 <Adapters xmlns="http://www.example.com/rsd/DataAccess">
   <Adapter Key="LASTCHANGEDATE" />
   <Adapter Key="AuditLogging" />
 </Adapters>
```

Output XML

```
<Adapters xmlns="http://www.example.com/rsd/DataAccess">
   <Adapter Key="LASTCHANGEDATE" />
   <Adapter Key="AuditLogging" />
   <Adapter Key="AutoExport" xmlns="" />
</Adapters>
```

How to prevent adding xmlns=" " in element.

Comment: @GSerg it isn't a duplicate of this question. He ask about removing namespace from **child** element not the root one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because in your input XML, all the elements belong to a namespace

```
<Adapters xmlns="http://www.example.com/rsd/DataAccess">
```

However, when you create the new `Adapter` element in your template, like so...

```
<Adapter Key="AutoExport">
```

You are actually creating a new element that does not belong to any namespace, and so the output has the `xmlns=''` present to indicate this.

One solution is to declare a default namespace in your XSLT, so that any unprefixed elements you create in your XSLT will then be part of this namespace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
  xmlns:x="http://www.example.com/rsd/DataAccess"  
  xmlns="http://www.example.com/rsd/DataAccess" exclude-result-prefixes="x">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:Adapter[@Key='AuditLogging']">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <Adapter Key="AutoExport" />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: your solution worked , it's not adding any xmlns=" ", but i noticed that , somehow the first line "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" of xml file is getting removed.

Comment: Try adding `omit-xml-declaration="no"` to the `xsl:output` statement.

Comment: omit-xml-declaration="no" doesn't  fix this issue

Comment: Tried   <xsl:output version="1.0" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"  indent="yes"/> also ..

Comment: It sounds like you have another issue that is unrelated to the issue with namespaces, so you might need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that below declaration in XSL

```
<xsl:template match="x:Adapter[@Key='AuditLogging']">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <Adapter Key="AutoExport">
    </Adapter>
 </xsl:template>
```

Creates new element in **different** xml namespace than root element (which has defined `xmlns="http://www.example.com/rsd/DataAccess"`)

The easiest method is to declare proper namespace in new element, but not all XSL compilers will remove it.

You can try also suggestion from [Define a default namespace for use in XSL XPaths with xpath-default-namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274166/define-a-default-namespace-for-use-in-xsl-xpaths-with-xpath-default-namespace) but I don't know which version are using