# How can I skip namespace definition when creating a variable in XSL 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Currently I'm defining a variable in my XSLT 1.x file like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns1="http://ns.hr-xml.org" >
...
    <xsl:variable name="my_var" select="ns1:RootNode/ns1:Node[3]/ns1:Title" />
```

Is there a way so that I can somehow define ns1: namespace to be always used so that I could possibly write my variable like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="my_var" select="RootNode/Node[3]/Title" />
```

Comment: If you were able to upgrade to XSLT 2.0, you would be able to use `xpath-default-namespace` to do this.

Comment: Thanks @TimC I did found it out but unfortunately I don't have this opportunity to use XSLT 2.0

Comment: Then I am not sure you can do much. You do see people doing something like `*[local-name() = 'RootNode']` but this would match all namespaces, not just the required one, and isn't really a good solution anyway.

Comment: @HrvojeGolcic Why is this a problem?

Comment: Also, you should not use xslt version 1.1. It was abandoned and is not supported by most processors. If you are writing a 1.0 stylesheet, declare it as `@version="1.0"

Comment: This is indeed not supported in XSLT 1.x, see the answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274166/define-a-default-namespace-for-use-in-xsl-xpaths-with-xpath-default-namespace. Another hacky workaround would be to prepend a transformation to remove all namespaces, but I don't even think that I should suggest this.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answer! @michael.hor257k it's not a problem, just out of couriousity.

Comment: @MadsHansen I didn't know that. Thanks for the hint