# NodeJS XPath.select expressions

Tags: node.js, xpath

I'm using xpath in a node.js application, but I can't figure out witch is the correct expression to select some nodes in my dom.

I've installed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath

This is my var **xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" 
        xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
  <url> 
    <loc>https://generic.net/it/diventa-promoter</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
        rel="alternate"
        hreflang="en"
        href="https://generic.net/en/become-promoter"
    />
    <image:image>
       <image:loc>https://generic.net/view/image/logo.jpg</image:loc>
       <image:caption>Logo</image:caption>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
       <image:loc>https://generic.net/view/image/step_1.jpg</image:loc>
       <image:caption>xxx</image:caption>
    </image:image>
  </url>
  <url> 
    <loc>https://generic.net/it/accedi</loc> 
  </url>
  <url> 
    <loc>https://generic.net/it/aggiungi-il-tuo-brand</loc> 
    <image:image>
       <image:loc>https://generic.net/view/image/how_it_works_it.jpg</image:loc>
       <image:caption>zzz?</image:caption>
    </image:image>
  </url>
  <url> 
    <loc>https://generic.net/it/domande-frequenti-brand</loc> 
  </url>
  <url> 
    <loc>https://generic.net/it/domande-frequenti-rivenditori</loc> 
  </url>
</urlset>
```

And this is my js code

```
var doc = new dom().parseFromString(xml);
var nodes = xpath.select("//loc", doc);
console.log(nodes);
```

But the results is --> [];

According to the documentation, this expression *"//loc"* must select all "loc" nodes. But is not working.
I can't select nothing. But if I select all ("//*"), this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your whole XML file is in a namespace. The first line

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" ...
```

sets the default namespace for all elements and therefore for the `loc` element. So either define a namespace with

```
var select = xpath.useNamespaces({"ns0": "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"});
```

and use it in the expression `//ns0:loc`.
Or ignore all namespaces on the `loc` elements with a predicate expression like

```
//*[local-name()='loc']
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Is there a way to completely ignore the namespaces? My document is having a `xmlns` attribute, and none of the elements is having a namespace prefix. Yet I have to supply `ns0:` prefixes in the XPath (like in your solution), which is really a pain. Like the OP, I'd like to rather use `//loc` instead of `//ns0:loc`. How can this be achieved? Looked through the docs of the `xpath` module, but everything I tried fails.
I am writing a script which is using user input for the xpath, and forcing users to always add `ns0` just doesnt feel right.

Comment: @user826955: The way to achieve ignoring the namespace is using `xpath-default-namespace` like described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14274280/1305969). But this requires a minimum of XSLT-2.0. If you cannot use version 2.0, you can either use a namespace-agnostic approach like `*[local-name()='element']` or create the correct namespace definitions.

Comment: @zx485: well I am not using XSLT, I am using the nodejs module `xpath` to select nodes from a dom document created by the `xmldom` nodejs module. There is no XSLT in this I am afraid.

Comment: @user826955: I'm sorry. I don't know about nodejs so I cannot help you in this regard. But you are free to create your own specific question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Actually, the OPs question is precisely what I would ask, and he's also asking for `node.js` and the `xpath` module. And he's neither using XSLT. But thanks anyway, guess there is just no way.

Comment: @user826955 There is in fact an undocumented option `allowAnyNamespaceForNoPrefix` but you can't just use it with the `xpath.select` API so you'd have to use the xpath library in a slightly different manner to take advantage of it. I've adapted the example in the question above here: https://runkit.com/verheyenkoen/62b1c424313f5b0008da7503